# Sending string from pc to arduino

Tags: string, serialization, serial-port, arduino

I have a string, specifically, a cellphone number with 11 digits inputted from a serial port(pc) and am planning to send it to arduino. I've got no problems in inputting the string  and print it to serial buffer, what I am confused about is, is arduino really correctly read the cellphone number that I've just inputted? In addition, let's assume that arduino have already read the string, how am I going to properly insert the string in my arduino code and process everything so that it can now send SMS? I was able to send SMS using the GSMSMS code alone. I was able to do it by manually inputting a specific cellphone number. But with the 1st arduino code below, I've got errors. Did i missed something? I badly need some suggestions and hints. Thanks in advance! :)))
Here is my arduino codes:

```
  char text[11];
  int  bufferIndex = 0;
  char Rx_data[50];
  unsigned char Rx_index = 0;
  int i = 0;
  char msg[160];
  int sig;


  void setup(){
  Serial.begin(38400);
      initGSM();
       loop_Serial();
      send_msg(text, "Your sample has been tested. You may now get your result. Thank you.");
  }

  void loop_Serial()
  {
      if( Serial.available())
    {
char ch = (char)Serial.read();
if( ch == '\n')  // is this the terminating carriage return
{
  text[ bufferIndex ] = 0; // terminate the string with a 0      
  bufferIndex = 0;  // reset the index ready for another string
  // do something with the string
  Serial.println(text);
}
else
  text[ bufferIndex++ ] = ch; // add the character into the buffer
    }
     } 

  void loop() {
    //none
  }

  void send_msg(char *number, char *msg)
  {
    char at_cmgs_cmd[30] = {'\0'};
    char msg1[160] = {'\0'};
    char ctl_z = 0x1A;

    sprintf(msg1, "%s%c", msg, ctl_z);
    sprintf(at_cmgs_cmd, "AT+CMGS=\"%s\"\r\n",number);

    sendGSM(at_cmgs_cmd);
    delay(100);
    delay(100);
    delay(100);
    sendGSM(msg1);
    delay(100);
  }

  void sendGSM(char *string){
    Serial.write(string);
    delay(90);
  }

  void clearString(char *strArray) {
    int j;
    for (j = 100; j > 0; j--)
      strArray[j] = 0x00;
  }

  void send_cmd(char *at_cmd, char clr){
    char *stat = '\0';
    while(!stat){
      sendGSM(at_cmd);
      delay(90);
      readSerialString(Rx_data);

      stat = strstr(Rx_data, "OK");
    }
    if (clr){
      clearString(Rx_data);
      delay(200);
      stat = '\0';
    }
  }

  void initGSM(){

    send_cmd("AT\r\n",1);                       
  //  send_cmd("ATE0\r\n",1); // Turn off automatic echo of the GSM Module  

    send_cmd("AT+CMGF=1\r\n",1);            // Set message format to text mode
    //Sucess

    Serial.println("Success");

    delay(1000);
    delay(1000);
    delay(1000);
  }

  void readSerialString (char *strArray) {

    if(!Serial.available()) {
      return;
    }

    while(Serial.available()) {
      strArray[i] = Serial.read();
      i++;
    }
  }
```

AT

AT+CMGF=1

Success

AT+CMGS="S"

Your sample has been tested. You may now get your result. Thank you.

Where "S" came from? And where's my inputted string?

Answer (score 0):

code is a bit messy.

First af all you should loop the serial until ALL 11 char are readed; actually you just look if there are character, but you don't whait for them

before loop_serial() do a while that block your progam until 11 char are ready to be readed:

```
while(Serial.available() < 11); //because of ; do nothing until there are 11 char
```

then you can read this char in a for, if there are remainig char then is up to you wrrite your error handling code.

to read, code in loop_serial is fine, BUT

```
Serial.print(inData);  
inData="";
inData.toCharArray(charBuf, 11);
```

so when you WILL read inData (actually you don't wait for char so probably you never enetered this loop), you print it, then you CLEAR it, the you copy the cleared string into a char array; also this is a buffer overflow, as you are copyng char that does not exits into charBuf, and if you don't clear inData, you should check if size is 11, or if less you still cause an overflow, witch may break many things in weird ways.

my tip is to write a code that just reade number on serial, and stress test it. When you'll have it work, it will be really easy to "concatenate" it with GSM sketch, ifact that part seems right :)

Comment: Hi lesto, I've updated my codes. Kindly check please above.. Now I'm getting "S" I don't know where it came from. :(

Comment: You are still not waiting for all 11 char, and also your ++ have to moved out of [ ]

Comment: I believe that that loop_Serial parts loops and loops until it reaches 11 characters and execute the rest of the program. I'm so confused :(((((

Comment: loop_serial has no loops and it is not inside a loop, so how is it supposed to loop?
it is justreading one char at the arduino startup, if is present

Comment: I tried inserting while(Serial.available() < 11); before the loop_Serial and the GSM code part did not proceed to execute. By the way, I got your point with loop_Serial is not a loop. hehehe :)

Comment: of course it does not execute, unltil you input at least 11 char! Also last cher must be a '\n' or yourcode won't add the '\0'.
Inmy opinion, OR you check for '\n' (and you loop until you find it) OR you wait for 11 char. Last solution is better IMHO

Comment: is if( ch == '\n')  // is this the terminating carriage return
not valid to use? my string by the way is from matlab..

Comment: ok, but then you have to wait for 12 char, 11 of number + '\n', or the rest of the code won't work as you will probably miss the '\n', and then the 0 wont be put at the end of the string, leading all the other function to overflow